# Exceptions thrown in the `OnLoad` method are ignored?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I have this piece of code

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

The program run fine and the exception I throw in the `OnLoad(EventArgs e)` is completely ignored. I've tested it in VS2012 .NET 4.5 both debug and release mode, same result. It's this normal and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the `Exceptions option` in your VS. If you look in the `Output` window, you should see there is a message printed like this **A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in...**

To enable the throwing exception, you can go to **Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions**, then you can expand the namespaces and find the exception you want, in your case it's `System.InvalidOperationException`. Then check the `Thrown` in the `Thrown` column.

[image]

Comment: You're right this work, but doesn't understand why only in the `OnLoad` the exception is ignored and not everywhere.